# Why I can't position text over image

Tags: html, css

I have one container div, inside I have two divs, one div is picture, another div is text.
I want to put text over image.
I set for div with picture `position:relative`, and for text div set `position:absolute;`

HTML:

```
<div class="headerAds">
            <div class="headerAdsPicture">
                <img src="img/adsbg.png" alt="Ad background picture">
            </div><!--Closed div headerAdsPicture-->
            <div class="headerAdsText">
                <span>This is text!</span>
            </div>
        </div><!--Closed div headerAds-->
```

CSS

```
.headerAdsPicture{
    position: relative;
}
.headerAdsText{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: `z-index` is your friend.

Comment: Just use the image as the background of the parent DIV that contains both.

Comment: The parent of `absolute element` must have `position:relative`, so give it to `.headerAds`, not `.headerAdsPicture`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
.headerAds{
    position: relative;
}
.headerAdsText{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

You should use `position:relative` on the **parent** of the child `position:absolute` you wish to use

```css
.headerAds{
    position: relative;
}
.headerAdsText{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerAds">
            <div class="headerAdsPicture">
                <img src="img/adsbg.png" alt="Ad background picture"/>
            </div><!--Closed div headerAdsPicture-->
            <div class="headerAdsText">
                <span>This is text!</span>
            </div>
        </div><!--Closed div headerAds-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code
HTML:

```
 <div class="headerAds">
         <div class="headerAdsText">
                    <span>This is text!</span>
                </div>
                <div class="headerAdsPicture">
                    <img src="http://stylonica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Beauty-of-nature-random-4884759-1280-800.jpg" alt="Ad background picture">
                </div><!--Closed div headerAdsPicture-->

            </div><!--Closed div headerAds-->
```

css:

```
.headerAdsPicture{
    position: relative;
}
.headerAdsText{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
    margin:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your missing

```
 z-index
```

Also if the image isnt anything important like a logo and is purely for background purposes you should think about getting rid of your image container and img tag and just adding `background-image` to your text wrapper.

as it was a little unclear in your question you may also require the use of `top:*distancFromTop*;`

---

```css
.headerAdsPicture {
  position: relative;
}
.headerAdsText {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:9999;
  top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerAds">
  <div class="headerAdsPicture">
    <img src="img/adsbg.png" alt="Ad background picture">
  </div>
  <!--Closed div headerAdsPicture-->
  <div class="headerAdsText">
    <span>This is text!</span>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Closed div headerAds-->
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work

```css
.headerAdsText{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
       .headerAdsPicture {
  za index:1;
       position: relative;
    }
    .headerAdsText {
      position: absolute;
      z-index:3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add `top: 0;` for `position: absolute`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.headerAds,
.headerAdsPicture{
    position: relative;
}
.headerAdsText{
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerAds">
            <div class="headerAdsPicture">
                <img src="http://khm0.googleapis.com/kh?v=169&hl=ru&x=340&y=480&z=10&token=13274" alt="Ad background picture" />
            </div><!--Closed div headerAdsPicture-->
            <div class="headerAdsText">
                <span>This is text!</span>
            </div>
        </div><!--Closed div headerAds-->
```

or

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.headerAds{
    background: url(http://khm0.googleapis.com/kh?v=169&hl=ru&x=340&y=480&z=10&token=13274) no-repeat center top;
    height: 256px;
    width: 256px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerAds">
            <!--<div class="headerAdsPicture">
                <img src="" alt="Ad background picture" />
            </div>-->
            <div class="headerAdsText">
                <span>This is text!</span>
            </div>
        </div><!--Closed div headerAds-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is you didn't give top or left position of your absolute div.

Give `top` value to `headerAdsText` will solve your issue.

Elements can be positioned using the top, bottom, left, and right properties when you use `position:absolute;`

```css
.headerAdsPicture{
    position: relative;
}
.headerAdsText{
    position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerAds">
            <div class="headerAdsPicture">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcneh.png" alt="Ad background picture">
            </div><!--Closed div headerAdsPicture-->
            <div class="headerAdsText">
                <span>This is text!</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can even do this without using `position:relative` and `position:absolute`

Look at this example:

```css
.headerAdsText {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -100px;
    text-align:center
    width:40%;
}

.headerAds {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerAds">
            <div class="headerAdsPicture">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Ad background picture">
            </div><!--Closed div headerAdsPicture-->
            <div class="headerAdsText">
                <span>This is text!</span>
            </div>
</div><!--Closed div headerAds-->
```